# Change escaped unicode to string in C#

Tags: c#, string, unicode, emoji

In c# I have

```
string x = @"\u0044\u0068\uD83D\uDE07\u90FD\u5728"
```

I need to turn it into:

```
Dh都在
```

How do I do that? Specifically, how do I know when \uD83D\uDE07 is one character as compared to two?

Comment: just remove the "@" at the beginning and print it. "@" makes it ignore the "\"s.

Comment: and character modifiers should get handled automatically, you shouldn't have to do anything special.

Comment: No @ErenErsönmez, that was just an example. string x contains those characters and I don't have control over how x is set. Unless you have a way to convert x to make it not ignore the escape characters.

Comment: Strange -- `` is `U+1F607`, not `U+D83D`.  Well: http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%F0%9F%98%87 shows it as `\ud83d\ude07`

Comment: I see. No, character literals would be a compile-time thing, can't make them after the fact.  You would have to parse the string, as seen in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might have to parse each char representation into an `int` and then convert to a `char`:

```
string x = @"\u0044\u0068\uD83D\uDE07\u90FD\u5728";
var chars = x.Split(new[]{@"\u"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(c => (char)Convert.ToInt32(c, 16))
    .ToArray();
var output = new string(chars);
// output = Dh都在
```

Answer (score 0):

I know [newtonsoft json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) will convert, so I would use that if was one of my projects and I already had references to it:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var output = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader($"\"{x}\"")).ReadAsString();

//output = Dh都在
```

Advantages are it's going to cope with nonunicode characters as well, I.e. `"Z\u0044" -> "ZD"`. Disadvantage is that in it's current state there are nonunicode characters it won't cope with, such as quote obviously: `"A\"B"` will fail.