# How to construct a unicode glyph key in C#

Tags: unicode, font-awesome, glyph

I am using FontAwesome to display glyphs in my Xamarin Android application. If I hardcode the glyph like this, where everything works fine:

```
 string iconKey = "\uf0a3";
 var drawable = new IconDrawable(this.Context, iconKey, "Font Awesome 5 Pro-Regular-400.otf").Color(Xamarin.Forms.Color.White.ToAndroid()).SizeDp(fontSize);
```

However, if what I have is the four letter code "f0a3" from [FontAwesome's cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet), stored in a string variable, I don't know how to set my iconKey variable to a value that works. Just concatenating a "\u" onto the beginning doesn't work, which makes sense since that's a Unicode escape indicator, not part of a standard string, but I don't know what to do instead. I also tried converting to and from Unicode in various random ways - e.g.

```
iconKey = unicode.GetChars(unicode.GetBytes("/u" + myFourChar.ToString())).ToString();
```

but unsurprisingly that didn't work either.

The IconDrawable is from [here](https://github.com/winstongubantes/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/CustomIconizeFont/CustomIconizeFont/CustomIconizeFont.Android/Custom/Utils/IconDrawable.cs). The value I send becomes an input there to the Paint.GetTextBounds method and the Canvas.DrawText method.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026517/change-escaped-unicode-to-string-in-c-sharp). Here is the code I am using, based on that post but simplified since I have only one hexadecimal character to handle:

```
string myString = "f0a3";
var chars = new char[] { (char)Convert.ToInt32(myString, 16) };
string iconKey = new string(chars);
var drawable = new IconDrawable(this.Context, iconKey, "Font Awesome 5 Pro-Regular-400.otf").Color(Xamarin.Forms.Color.White.ToAndroid()).SizeDp(fontSize);
```